# Cannot create PRIMARY KEY in Maria dB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to create two tables named as `department` and `dept_locations`.

I already  created the `department` table

SQL:

```
create table department(
dname varchar(15) unique,
dumber int primary key,
mgr_ssn char(9) not null,
mgr_start_date date,
foreign key(mgr_ssn) references employee(ssn));
```

Now I want to create the table `dept_locations`

SQL:

```
create table dept_locations
(
dnumber int,
dlocation varchar(15),
primary key(dnumber,dlocation),
foreign key(dnumber) references department(dnumber));
```

But upon creating `dept_locations` it gives me error. Like

> Foreign key constraint incorrectly formed'.

Any one have solution for this??

Comment: Close it its only a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary key in department is named `dumber` while your foreign key reference in `dept_locations` is named `dnumber`.

Comment: Thank you man. Appreciate it.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please mark it as selected. Thanks.

Comment: Ok found it. Thanks